# Date format in PowerBI Desktop client is different than the one published. Sorting doesn't work

Tags: powerbi

I have a strange issue.

I sort my report by date in this format. 02-Nov-17 9:59 AM etc. When i use the PowerBI Desktop , it sorts the report fine.

When i publish it , the date is displayed in this format 09-02-17 . So because of this the sorting is not working correctly online.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by changing local of specific date column